# Finite limsup of subsequence implies finite limsup of sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is the following result obvious? Or just wrong?

> Let $a_n$ be a non-negative, non-decreasing sequence of real numbers. Let $\delta \in (0,1)$ and assume that $$\tag{I}\limsup_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_{2^k}}{\log(2^k)2^{k\delta}} < \infty,$$ then already $$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{\log(n)n^\delta} < \infty.$$

Is it that the sequence $\frac{a_{n}}{\log(n)n^\delta}$ either diverges or converges under the given assumptions? And we could thus replace the $limsup$ in (I) by $lim$ and then the statement would hold trivially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k_n = \lceil \log_2 n \rceil$ so that $2^{k_n-1} < n \le 2^{k_n}$.
$$
\frac{a_n}{\log(n) n^\delta}
\le \frac{a_{2^{k_n}}}{\log(2^{k_n-1}) 2^{(k_n-1)\delta}}
= 2^\delta \frac{k_n}{k_n-1} \frac{a_{2^{k_n}}}{\log(2^{k_n}) 2^{k_n\delta}}
\le 4 \frac{a_{2^{k_n}}}{\log(2^{k_n}) 2^{k_n\delta}}.$$

Take the $\limsup$ of both sides and use (I).